# Elasticsearch sorting on runtime_mapping type "lookup"

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, mapping, lookup, elasticsearch-painless

Trying to sort the value from a runtime_mapping "lookup" value from a second index. I can see the value if I remove the sort. Have tried directly sorting and using various painless sort scripts. Is this not ready for prime time (added v8.2) or is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is the parent index:

```json
 {
    "oir_pr_lh_2021": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "subToiId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the lookup index:

```json
{
    "sub_toi_lk": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is search that shows the lookup works:

```json
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "subToiLk": {
            "type": "lookup",
            "target_index": "sub_toi_lk",
            "input_field": "subToiId",
            "target_field": "id",
            "fetch_fields": [
                "name"
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "subToiId",
        "subToiLk"
    ],
    "_source": false
}
```

Partial results:

```json
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 14,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "oir_pr_lh_2021",
        "_id": "1423949",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "subToiLk": [
            {
              "name": [
                "Individual Medicare Supplement - Medicare Select"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "subToiId": [
            732
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now trying to sort:

```json
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "subToiLk": {
            "type": "lookup",
            "target_index": "sub_toi_lk",
            "input_field": "subToiId",
            "target_field": "id",
            "fetch_fields": [
                "name"
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "string",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['subToiLk.name'].value"
            },
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    "fields": [
        "subToiId",
        "subToiLk"
    ],
    "_source": false
}
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "shard": 0,
  "index": "oir_pr_lh_2021",
  "node": "ka3YrBmnRCSxjD0eF60KXw",
  "reason": {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.getFactoryForDoc(LeafDocLookup.java:127)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:171)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:32)",
      "doc['subToiLk.name'].value",
      "    ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "doc['subToiLk.name'].value",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
      "offset": 4,
      "start": 0,
      "end": 26
    },
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "No field found for [subToiLk.name] in mapping"
    }
  }
}
```

changing "script" to :

```json
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['subToiLk'].value"
    }
}
```

returns

```json
{
  "shard": 0,
  "index": "oir_pr_lh_2021",
  "node": "ka3YrBmnRCSxjD0eF60KXw",
  "reason": {
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MappedFieldType.fielddataBuilder(MappedFieldType.java:101)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:102)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.index.query.SearchExecutionContext.lambda$lookup$2(SearchExecutionContext.java:500)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.SearchLookup.getForField(SearchLookup.java:114)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$2.run(LeafDocLookup.java:136)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup$2.run(LeafDocLookup.java:132)",
      "java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.getFactoryForDoc(LeafDocLookup.java:132)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:171)",
      "org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:32)",
      "doc['subToiLk'].value",
      "    ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "doc['subToiLk'].value",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
      "offset": 4,
      "start": 0,
      "end": 21
    },
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [subToiLk] of type [lookup]"
    }
  }
}
```

and just using a plain sort statement:

```json
{
    "sort": [
            "subToiLk.name"
    ],
}
```

Returns this error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "No mapping found for [subToiLk.name] in order to sort on",
                "index_uuid": "eKAO5aYJQuKMK3t1ZaOPcQ",
                "index": "oir_pr_lh_2021"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a run time field inside a script? You can use it just like a `normal` field for sorting. and yes - it's production ready.

Comment: Yes I am. My attempts to use it like a normal field for sorting generate an error of either "reason": "No field found for [subToiLk.name] in mapping" or "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [subToiLk] of type [lookup]". Please tell me what I doing incorrectly to use this field.

Answer (score 0):

Fields that are retrieved by runtime fields of type lookup can be used to enrich the hits in a search response. It’s not possible to query or aggregate on these fields.